Implementing GraphQl using go fiber
I am trying to implement graphQl using go fiber framework till now the grapgql playground is displaying in my system but a i am not able to configure the database connection so that i can access all the database record i have to manuallly configure the database tables record such as if i have users tables in my datatables so using command go run  "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/" create a schema and various files like models_gen.go ,generated.go ,resolver.go ,schema.graphls and schema.resolver.go  i can access users tables
i just want to use all the database record in the graphql in go fiber without defining struct for every tables in my database how can i do that can someone help me
**Code Which i am using **
func GetGraphql(session *session.Store, enforcer *casbin.Enforcer, dbpool *pgxpool.Pool) fiber.Handler {
   return func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // Database := graph.Connect()

        resolver := &graph.Resolver{Dbpool: dbpool}
        srv := handler.NewDefaultServer(graph.NewExecutableSchema(graph.Config{Resolvers: resolver}))
        if ctx.Method() == fiber.MethodGet && ctx.Path() == "/graphql" {
            wrapHandler(playground.Handler("GraphQL Playground", "/graphql"))(ctx)
            return nil
        }
        // Handle GraphQL queries for POST requests
        if ctx.Method() == fiber.MethodPost && ctx.Path() == "/graphql" {
            wrapHandler(srv.ServeHTTP)(ctx)
            return nil
        }
        return ctx.Status(fiber.StatusNotFound).SendString("Not Found")
    }
}
func wrapHandler(f func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) {
    return func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) {
        fasthttpadaptor.NewFastHTTPHandler(http.HandlerFunc(f))(ctx.Context())
    }
}

